# How to fix "Exception evaluating SpringEL expression" error after submitting a variable Spring/Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, forms, thymeleaf

I am using Spring Boot/Thymeleaf to create a form that accepts an email address, redirects to a results page that displays the accepted email and sends it to a third party API (authenticated with Oauth2). I am having trouble with the form portion, I am attempting to use Thymeleaf to accept the input to display it on the result.html page. I am receiving an error when trying to display it on the results page, full error is:

```
[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-4] Exception processing template "result.html": Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "signup.email" (template: "result.html" - line 10, col 4)
```

I was attempting to follow the examples provided here: 
https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/

I have attempted to modify the controller from `@PostMapping` and `@GetMapping` to `@RequestMapping` and add commenting described in a workaround such as:

```
<!--/*@thymesVar id="signup" type="com.mainconfig.controller1"*/-->
```

Here is the `signup.html` code containing the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<html>
<head>
    <title>My Jmml</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body style="background-color: #2B2B2B">
<br /><br />
<h2 style="text-align:center">Contact Information</h2>
<!-- Input Form -->

<!--/*@thymesVar id="signup" type="com.mainconfig.controller1"*/-->
<form action="#" th:action="@{/signup}" th:object="${signup}" method="post">
    <div align="center">
        <label>Email Address</label><br /><br />
        <!--/*@thymesVar id="email" type="String"*/-->
        <input type="text" th:field="*{email}" placeholder="Email" required />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input class="submitbutton" type='submit' value='Submit'/>
        <br />
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Results page that should display the email (result.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Thank you for your submission!</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Thank you for your submission!</h1>

<p th:text="'Email: ' + ${signup.email}" />

<a href="/index">Submit another message</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class controller1 {

    @RequestMapping (value = "/home")
    public String home(Model model) {
        return "index.html";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String signupForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("signup", new emailInput());
        return "signup.html";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String signupSubmit(@ModelAttribute("email") emailInput email) {
        return "result.html";
    }


}
```

Expected output should be the email variable displayed on the results page after it being gathered in the signup form.

If you have a recommendation on how to better do what I am attempting, I am open to suggestions! I am very new to Spring/Thymeleaf but have had experience with Java/Jsp. Thank you for any help, please let me know if you need anything else to help!

Comment: I highly doubt that your form is your controller. However the actual error is in your `result.html` form. You have an object named `email` NOT an object names `signup`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will be a starting point for you.
Make sure you place the html files under /resources/templates.

I changed a bit your signup html and result.html as follows, they are still not perfect(avoid using inline styles and use an external stylesheet!):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">

<head>
    <title>My Jmml</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body style="background-color: #2B2B2B">
<br /><br />
<h2 style="text-align:center">Contact Information</h2>
<!-- Input Form -->

<!--/*@thymesVar id="signup" type="com.mainconfig.controller1"*/-->
<form th:action="@{/signup}" th:object="${signup}" method="post">
    <div align="center">
        <label>Email Address</label><br /><br />
        <!--/*@thymesVar id="email" type="String"*/-->
        <input type="text" th:field="*{email}" placeholder="Email" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input class="submitbutton" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        <br />
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

and the result.html looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<head>
    <title>Thank you for your submission!</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Thank you for your submission!</h1>

<p th:text="'Email: ' + ${email}" />

<a href="/index">Submit another message</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I also created a form object, add additional fields here if you want

```
public class SignUpForm {
    //you can put some annotations here if you want for validating the email
    //for e.g @NotEmpty or a @Pattern(regexp to validate the email)
    private String email;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

and in the end your Controller. I pass the email from the signup post request to the result.html via a flash attribute:

```
@Controller
public class Controller1 {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String signupForm(@ModelAttribute("signup") SignUpForm form) {
        return "/signup";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String signupSubmit(@ModelAttribute("signup") SignUpForm form, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        //validate form first -> check bindingResult documentation

        //do what you need with your form object

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("email", form.getEmail());
        return "redirect:/result";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/result", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String result() {
        return "/result";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem, looking at how you have it setup, it looks like my biggest issues were signup.email on the results page and what you did with the controller! I did have a form object, I wasnt sure what files I needed to get help with the question. Thank you again! If you do read this, is inside the .post controller for the signup where I would want to put the http calls to the third party api I am working with?